# I want to add text field when i clicked the button "add". But it doesn't work. Help me

Tags: javascript, eclipse, swing, user-interface, textfield

this is my code. I want to let the user add a new text field as they want, but it only can add one text field. will loop for `Participant` gonna work?

```js
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.SystemColor;


    public class General {


        private JFrame frame;
        private JTextField textFirst;

        /**
         * Launch the application.
         */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        General window = new General();
                        
                      window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    
                       } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    

                     }
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Create the application.
         */
        public General() {
            initialize();


        }

        /**
         * Initialize the contents of the frame.
         */
        private void initialize() {
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            
            JLabel lblInsertParticipantsTerm = new JLabel("Insert Participants Term :");
            lblInsertParticipantsTerm.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
            lblInsertParticipantsTerm.setBounds(34, 32, 169, 14);
            frame.getContentPane().add(lblInsertParticipantsTerm);
            
            textFirst = new JTextField();
            textFirst.setBounds(23, 52, 180, 20);
            frame.getContentPane().add(textFirst);
            textFirst.setColumns(10);
            
            JButton button = new JButton("ADD");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    JTextField newTextField = new JTextField(20);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(newTextField);
                    frame.validate();
                    frame.repaint();
                
                  }
            });
            button.setBounds(205, 51, 53, 23);
            frame.getContentPane().add(button);
            
            JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
            textArea.setBackground(SystemColor.control);
            textArea.setBounds(23, 52, 180, 199);
            frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);
        }
  }
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not at all related. Your question is about Java.

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a layout manager.  Do the following:

```
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

Comment: I tried it but still the text field not appear.
JButton btnAdd = new JButton("ADD");
    btnAdd.setBackground(SystemColor.control);
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField newTextField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(newTextField);
        newTextField.setColumns(10);
        panel.validate();
        panel.repaint();});
 panel.setBounds(23, 48, 155, 225);
 frame.getContentPane().add(panel);}
});btnAdd.setBounds(188, 48, 69, 23);
 frame.getContentPane().add(btnAdd);

Comment: In the original code, if you simply do what I suggested where you had originally set to `null` more text fields would appear for each button press.  Please do not change the code and then expect everything to work as you may introduce new errors.  Also, do not put code in comments as it is hard to read.